# React with hooks, closing accordion using button inside accordion

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-bootstrap

I'm using an accordion to show history, and have a Clear History button within the accordion.  I want to close the accordion when the Clear History button is clicked.  It does clear the history, and changes the direction of the chevron, but doesn't actually close the accordion.

My Accordion:

```
    <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
      <Card>
        <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="1" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
          Roll History { open ? <FaChevronUp /> : <FaChevronDown/> }
        </Accordion.Toggle>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="1">
          <Card.Body>
            {historyText.length > 0 &&
              <Button onClick={clearHistory} variant="primary" size="sm">
                Clear History
              </Button>
            }
            {historyText}
          </Card.Body>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
      </Card>
    </Accordion>
```

My clear history code:

```
  const clearHistory = () => {
    setHistoryText([]);
    setOpen(!open);
  }
```

**Update
Based on a comment that has been deleted, I made the following changes:

```
const [key, setKey] = useState("1");
```

Then in my clear code:

```
setKey("0");
```

Then I set the eventKey:

```
<Accordion.Collapse eventKey={key}>
```

At this point it works for one round, but I don't have anything to set it back to a 1.

Comment: If I change eventKey to "0" on click, it closes the accordion.  However if I change eventKey to "1" on a later action or reset, it automatically opens the accordion.  So I can close it, however I can't reset the accordion so that it acts naturally again.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the chevron changes is because of this line:

`{ open ? <FaChevronUp /> : <FaChevronDown/> }`

But I don't see anywhere else you are checking for `open` to decide whether to close or open the accordion.

I don't know your whole codebase well enough to say where it should go. But it seems that somewhere else you should be checking the value of `open` (maybe where you render `<Card.Body>`?

Comment: The only other accordion or card code is from the import, `import Accordion from 'react-bootstrap/Accordion';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';`

Comment: To open and close the accordion, I click on the header.  That closes the Card.Body